# Split a Date column into Start and End columns based on ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Given three columns ID, S/E, and Date (there are two rows for each ID) we want to Split the Date column into two columns Start and End based on Matching ID and S/E.

[image]

I have tried a couple of options.

Approach 1
So, far I was doing it by using a table:

Column Start:

```
=IF([@[S/E]]="Start",[@[Date]],"")
```

Column End:

```
=IF([@[S/E]]="End",[@[Date]],"")
```

[image]

I would like for the Date under Start and End column to show on every row.
Like:
[image]

Then Add a column that calculates the difference between the dates:

```
Function TestDates(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long
       TestDates = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2)
End Function
```

Column DateFif

```
=ABS(TestDates([@[End]],[@[Start]]))
```

Approach 2
I have also tried the following Macro

```
Sub ConcatenateCellsIfSameValues()
    Dim xCol As New Collection
    Dim xSrc As Variant
    Dim xRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    xSrc = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
    Set xRg = Range("D1")
    On Error Resume Next
    For I = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
        xCol.Add xSrc(I, 1), TypeName(xSrc(I, 1)) & CStr(xSrc(I, 1))
    Next I
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim xRes(1 To xCol.Count + 1, 1 To 2)
    xRes(1, 1) = "No"
    xRes(1, 2) = "Combined Date"
    For I = 1 To xCol.Count
        xRes(I + 1, 1) = xCol(I)
        For J = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
            If xSrc(J, 1) = xRes(I + 1, 1) Then
                xRes(I + 1, 2) = xRes(I + 1, 2) & ", " & xSrc(J, 2)
            End If
        Next J
        xRes(I + 1, 2) = Mid(xRes(I + 1, 2), 2)
    Next I
    Set xRg = xRg.Resize(UBound(xRes, 1), UBound(xRes, 2))
    xRg.NumberFormat = "@"
    xRg = xRes
    xRg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Which could be a good start but not sure how to tune for this goal
[image]

THANKS and ANY help is appreciated it!
(Even better if the macro is for a table)

Comment: are Id-S/E combos unique?  as in there is always just one Id for each start and one id for each end?

Comment: @Scott Yes, that is correct. Only one Start and one End per ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMIFS()

Start:

```
 =SUMIFS([Date],[S/E],"Start",[Trade Id],[@Trade Id])
```

End:

```
=SUMIFS([Date],[S/E],"End",[Trade Id],[@Trade Id])
```

For the date diff, no need for vba:

```
=INT(ABS([@End]-[@Start]))
```

[image]